# Fabric - IText flipY baseline position

Tags: fabricjs

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/n6ucz/

```
function flipY () {
    var el = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!el) {
        alert ("select obj first");
        return;
    }

    el.flipY = !el.flipY;
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

When you try to flip the IText vertically, the baseline position is not what I expected, the line in the image is what I have added from fabric.Line object, not from IText, the first one is text before flipY, the second one is the same text after it's flipped vertically, and the third one is what I expected after it's flipped vertically:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't understand from your question what is the expected behavior that your trying to achieve, even though i would recommend to set the padding to 0.

Comment: Sorry let me expain, I expect the text is at the same level after it's flipped, you see the two images, the second one is the flipped text, and the text bottom line not included Bounding Rect should be as same as the first one, apparently it have more space then. I set padding = 0, and it didn't work too.